# Unable to combine the rows in sql by group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to combine three rows as a single row in sql server 2005, i have tried with group by clause, but i could not combine the three rows into a single row

Below is the code, what i have written

```
select * from 
(
select 
   case 
   when  postatus = 'y' and  approverid = '1111' 
   then Convert(varchar(10),  trasdate ,103) 
   end as [col1],
   case
   when  postatus = 'y' and  approverid = '401'
   then Convert(varchar(10),  trasdate ,103)
   end as [col2],
   case
   when  postatus = 'y' and ( approverid = '329' or  approverid = '1495' or  approverid = '1239')
   then Convert(varchar(10),  trasdate ,103)
   end as [col3]
from tblpo_approvalstatus where prnumber = '000002'
) as t
group by
col1,col2,col3
```

i got the result as

```
col1      col2       col3
9/6/2015  NULL       NULL
NULL      9/8/2015   NULL
NULL      NULL       9/15/2015
```

I want them as a single row

```
col1       col2         col3
9/6/2015   9/8/2015     9/15/2015
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly post what you've tried please.

Comment: @Thorsten, In the result, i want single row as 2 fgh cde abc, thanks

Comment: And if there is also a record for col1=3; would you want two result rows, one for 2, one for 3, or just one? If one: which value do you expect in col1 then? And what if there are two records for col1=2 with two different values for col2, say fgh and ijk: which value would you show?

Comment: @ thorsten , following is the partial code of my sp, select * from 
(
select 
case 
   when  postatus = 'y' and  approverid = '1111' 
   then Convert(varchar(10),  trasdate ,103) 
   end as [col1],
  case
   when  postatus = 'y' and  approverid = '401'
   then Convert(varchar(10),  trasdate ,103)
   end as [col2],
  case
   when  postatus = 'y' and ( approverid = '329' or  approverid = '1495' or  approverid = '1239')
   then Convert(varchar(10),  trasdate ,103)
   end as [col3]
from tblpo_approvalstatus where prnumber = '000002'
) as t
group by
col1,col2,col3

Comment: i got the result as 

col1 col2 col3

9/6/2015 NULL NULL

NULL 9/8/2015 NULL

NULL NULL 9/15/2015

but i want to combine three rows as single row

col1 col2  col3

9/6/2015 9/8/2015 9/15/2015

Comment: @ Thorsten, Thanks for helping me to post the question clearly.

Comment: Okay, so no grouping column any longer. And you expect to get three records, one with a col1 value, one with a col2 value and one with a col3 value. But can it happen that you get four records instead? E.g. two values for col1? If so, what would you want to do then?

Comment: No, i want, what you have said,one with a col1 value, one with a col2 value and one with a col3 value, i am working on a report, if i fix this, the entire report will not have duplicate records or it will be having less rows to refer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
select no, max([po date]), max([pr date]), max([qar date])
from t
group by no;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to aggregate your data, so use aggregate functions. In your case where there is only one value per column (because `prnumber` + `postatus` + `approverid` are unique in that table? maybe they build the primary key?), you can use MIN or MAX or even AVG, it makes no difference.

```
select 
  convert(varchar(10), max(case when postatus = 'y' and approverid = '1111' then trasdate end) ,103) as col1,
  convert(varchar(10), max(case when postatus = 'y' and approverid = '401' then trasdate end) ,103) as col2,
  convert(varchar(10), max(case when postatus = 'y' and approverid in ('329','1495','1239') then trasdate end) ,103) as col3
from tblpo_approvalstatus 
where prnumber = '000002';
```

GROUP BY would be absolutely out of place here, by the way. With `GROUP BY x, y` you say "please aggregate my data such that I get a result row per x and y", but you don't want to get one result row *per* something; you want one result row *at all* (so not GROUP BY).

Comment: Thank you very much, i am getting the result in the table, i am trying to put the code in stored procedure, Thanks a lot